# IpOverUsbSvc service is terminated when Windows Phone device is connected

Tags: windows-phone-7, deployment, windows-phone-8, windows-services, windows-phone

I'm trying to deploy windows phone application to device and every time i'm getting the following error:

> Error 16  Connection to device failed. For connecting to Windows Phone
>   8 device - Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc) is not
>   running. Retry after starting Windows Phone IP over USB Transport
>   (IpOverUsbSvc) from the services management console. For Windows Phone
>   7 device - Zune software is not launched. Retry after making sure that
>   Zune software is launched.        0   0

I went to the services console and discovered that IpOverUsbSvc is down. Unfortunately I failed to restart it with the following error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dp7hv9crhdoz6t3/IpOverUsbSvc_Error.png

When I went to the event log I found the following:

```
Application: IpOverUsbSvc.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 0FE7BEED

Faulting application name: IpOverUsbSvc.exe, version: 8.0.9903.0, time stamp: 0x505d196a
Faulting module name: IpOverUsbPc.DLL, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x505d1a08
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0001beed
Faulting process id: 0x18fc
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf11eacc0716b2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0\Bin\IpOverUsbSvc.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\11.0\Bin\IpOverUsbPc.DLL
Report Id: 3135e02f-7dde-11e3-bec2-88532e5eb25c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Then I disconnected my phone and was able to restart the service. It was up and running. Unfortunately when I connected my phone again service was terminated right away with the same errors (above).

Please advise.

Comment: Is your device being detected by the PC?Is your device driver updated?

Comment: yes, it is detected and even "Windows Phone" metro app which syncs photos could see the phone and read the content. I check the same phone at another computer and was able to deploy the app there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem some time back.. Can you pls try uninstalling your device driver and installing it again. This may resolve your error..

Answer (score 1):

I come here to bring solution that u might like
I suggest you to try open service menu on your OS Windows [here's the screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McaAf.png)

on the form try to search Windows phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)then u should right click and Start it
then you may deploy your apps and see whether this solution works or no.